# VB.net - HttpWebRequest POST (login to Instagram.com)

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how will see log into sites like instagram.com, as I have the same question for twitter, my doubt comes when trying to log in by code without the webbrowser using method post in vb.net, trying to use this code returns me on instagram Error 404:

```
Dim postData As String = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" & TextBox1.Text & "&username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = cokkie
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
```

I get the csrfmiddlewaretoken the instagram page by method get, really do not understand, but I think I read that I must first get a cookie before log in, but really do not know, if anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

trying to simulate a user logging into the normal web sight seems like hard work, Instagram supports OAuth 2.0 and if you search Nuget for OAuth you will find a whole load of packages to to the work for you.

for reference you can find twitter info at https://dev.twitter.com/docs

Tim

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, but I will not use the API for that, there are ways to do it without using the API, Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, we actually need to send cookies to be able to logging, the code here for those people who have the same question:
Public cokkie As CookieContainer

```
    Public Sub cookie()
    'Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    'Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("https://instagram.com/accounts/login")
    Dim postData As String = ""
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com/accounts/login"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    cokkie = tempCookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
    TextBox1.Text = cokkie.ToString
    Dim regx As New Regex("name=""csrfmiddlewaretoken"" value=""(.*?)""/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim mactches As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(thepage)
    For Each match As Match In mactches
        TextBox1.Text = match.Value
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("name=""csrfmiddlewaretoken"" value=""", "")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("""/>", "")
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub log()
    Dim postData As String = "csrfmiddlewaretoken=" & TextBox1.Text & "&username=xxxx&password=xxxx"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com/accounts/login/"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = cokkie
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/"
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
End Sub
```