# Check Instagram user by httpwebrequest vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I want to check if my username is avalaibe on isntagram or no !

so i write this simple code using httpwebrequest with to get handchake but i have an error when get response !! any one have a idea of this ?

my code :!

```
 Dim logincookie As CookieContainer
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
    Dim postData As String = "email=&password=&username=" & TextBox1.Text & "&first_name=&opt_into_one_tap=false"
    Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
    Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
    Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

    Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/web_create_ajax/attempt/"), HttpWebRequest)
    postReq.Method = "POST"
    postReq.KeepAlive = True
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    postReq.Referer = "https://www.instagram.com/"
    'postReq.UserAgent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse
    postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
    logincookie = tempCookies
    Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd
    Dim s As String = thepage
    If s.Contains("coreSpriteInputAccepted gBp1f") Then
        Label1.Text = "valid"
    ElseIf s.Contains("coreSpriteInputError") Then
        Label1.Text = "invalid"
    Else
        Label1.Text = "unknow !"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757296/vb-net-httpwebrequest-post-login-to-instagram-com) post?

Comment: yep i did seen ..